# C# Console project. How do i repeat 3 messages during file.copy action

Tags: c#, console, filecopy

FYI this is my 1st ever C# Project so forgive me any shortcomings

This is my current code is..

```
            if (File.Exists(InstallFolder + StrFilename))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nSQS App Found");
                File.Delete(InstallFolder + StrFilename);
                Console.WriteLine("Updating the Quotation System, Please Wait...");
                File.Copy(StrServerFolder + StrFilename, InstallFolder + StrFilename);
                Console.WriteLine("Done. Launching the SQS App...");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(InstallFolder + StrFilename);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
```

My Target is to display
`"Updating the Quotation System, Please Wait."` then overwrite this line with `"Updating the Quotation System, Please Wait.."` and final over write `"Updating the Quotation System, Please Wait..."`
repeat these messages until `"File.Copy(StrServerFolder + StrFilename, InstallFolder + StrFilename);"` has completed.
it may be easier to split the message in 2 parts with `{.} {..} {...}` at the end of the string

i have tried various apporaches tried google adding text to my CS file found on line, gave me errors in VS ( probably be cause i did'nt understand the structure.

Any help would be appreciated its a small programme i like to keep it a simple as possibe.

TIA

Comment: You can use asynchronous methods. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated (example) code which might work for you

```
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nSQS App Found");
        var awaiter = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (!File.Exists(InstallFolder + StrFilename)) return;
            File.Delete(InstallFolder + StrFilename);
            File.Copy(StrServerFolder + StrFilename, InstallFolder + StrFilename);
        }).GetAwaiter();

        var i = 1;
        while (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Updating the Quotation System, Please Wait" + new string('.', i));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            i++;
        }

        awaiter.OnCompleted(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done. Launching the SQS App...");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(InstallFolder + StrFilename);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Mukul. your upoded code really worked for me. for some reason the OnComplete code wouldnt work from the "Thread.sleep(2000);" line so added the last 3 lines outside of the loop. any ideas why this would be? and thanks again!